# How to get the element which are diagonal to a certain index in an array which represents a rectangle

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

Consider an array whose length will be always product of two numbers. For below array `l` is 4 and `w` is `5`.

There is also a given index. I want to get the two arrays containing elements which lie on the diagonal line which passes through that particular index.

```
[
    0,  1,  2,  3,  4
    5,  6,  7,  8,  9
    10, 11, 12, 13, 14
    15, 16, 17, 18, 19
]  

index = 7 => [3, 7, 11, 15] and [1, 7, 13, 19]
index = 16 => [4, 8, 12, 16] and [10, 16]
index = 0 => [0, 6, 12, 18] and [0]
```

I have tried following:

```js
let arr = Array(20).fill().map((x,i) => i);

function getDias(arr, l, w, ind){
  let arr1 = [];
  let arr2 = [];
  
  for(let i = 0;i<l;i++){
    arr1.push(arr[ind + (i * w) + i])
    arr1.push(arr[ind - (i * w) - i])
    arr2.push(arr[ind + (i * w) + i])
    arr2.push(arr[ind - (i * w) - i])
  }
  const remove = arr => [...new Set(arr.filter(x => x !== undefined))];
  return [remove(arr1),remove(arr2)];

}
console.log(getDias(arr, 4, 5, 7))
```

The code have two problems. Both the arrays in the result are same. And secondly they are not in order.

**Note:** I don't want to use `sort()` to reorder the array. And also I don't want loop through all 20 elements. Just want to get the elements of that diagonal row

Answer (score 4):

Some math (ie, modulus, integer division, and minimums) can find the beginning row and column for both the diagonal that runs left-to-right (LTR) and right-to-left (RTL), saving complexity of iterating backwards to find the starting points.  Then, using those beginning rows and columns, simply iterate until outside the height and width bounds of the array.

```
let arr = Array(20).fill().map((x, i) => i);

function diagonals(arr, h, w, n) {
  var nRow = Math.floor(n / w);
  var nCol = n % w;

  let LTR = [];
  for (let r = nRow - Math.min(nRow, nCol), c = nCol - Math.min(nRow, nCol); r < h && c < w; r++, c++) LTR.push(arr[r * w + c]);

  let RTL = [];
  for (let r = nRow - Math.min(nRow, w - nCol - 1), c = nCol + Math.min(nRow, w - nCol - 1); r < h && 0 <= c; r++, c--) RTL.push(arr[r * w + c]);

  return [LTR, RTL];
}
```

Sample runs...

```
diagonals(arr, 4, 5, 7);  // returns ==> [[1, 7, 13, 19], [3, 7, 11, 15]]
diagonals(arr, 4, 5, 15); // returns ==> [[15], [3, 7, 11, 15]]
```

**Edit:  Note on `arr` value vs index.**

Also, just a point of clarification.  The question indicates "There is also a given index. I want to get the two arrays containing elements which lie on the diagonal line which passes through that particular index."  If the index of the rectangular array is being sought rather than the actual value of `arr`, then there is no need to build `arr`, and subsequently the `function` and `push` statements can be changed to...

- `function diagonals(h, w, n)`
- `LTR.push(r * w + c)`
- `RTL.push(r * w + c)`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code

```js
let arr = Array(20).fill().map((x,i) => i);

function getDias(arr, l, w, ind){
  let arr1 = [];
  let arr2 = [];
  n = l*w;
  lVal = Math.floor(ind/w);
  rVal = ind%w;
  temp1  = lVal;
  temp2  = rVal;
  while(temp1>=0 && temp2>=0){
    val = ((w*temp1) + temp2);
    arr1.unshift(arr[val]);  
    temp1--;
    temp2--;
  }
  temp1  = lVal;
  temp2  = rVal;
  temp1++;
  temp2++;
  while(temp1<l && temp2<w){
    val = ((w*temp1) + temp2);
    arr1.push(arr[val]);  
    temp1++;
    temp2++;
  }

   
  console.log(arr1);
  temp1  = lVal;
  temp2  = rVal;
  while(temp1>=0 && temp2<w){
    val = ((w*temp1) + temp2);
    arr2.unshift(arr[val]);  
    temp1--;
    temp2++;
  }
  
  temp1  = lVal;
  temp2  = rVal;
  temp1++;
  temp2--;
  while(temp1<l && temp2>=0){
    val = ((w*temp1) + temp2);
    arr2.push(arr[val]);  
    temp1++;
    temp2--;
  }

  console.log(arr2);

}
getDias(arr, 4, 5, 7);
getDias(arr, 4, 5, 16);
getDias(arr, 4, 5, 0);
```

The idea is to compute l_val  and r_val.

```
l_val = index/w
r_val = index%w
```

Now arr[l_val][r_val] marks the position in the matrix found by l_val* w+ r_val

This is now followed by 4 steps:

1) Start iteration from arr[l_val][r_val]. Subtract 1 from both till we reach the end. Unshift this to array_1 (to maintain order)

2) Start iteration from [l_val][r_val].Add 1 to both till we reach the end. Push this to array_1.

3) Start iteration from arr[l_val][r_val]. Subtract 1 from l_val and add 1 t r_val till we reach the end. Unshift this to array_2 (to maintain order)

4) Start iteration from [l_val][r_val].Add 1 to l_val and subtract 1 from r_val till we reach the end. Push this to array_2.

Comment: I really thank you for giving time. But I don't need such complex code. I remember I did this very simply. But unfortunately I lost that code...

Comment: @MaheerAli By complex, you mean the number of lines or the time taken to execute this? Because the latter is not that much

Comment: The no of lines.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let arr = Array(20).fill().map((x, i) => i);

function getDias(arr, l, w, ind) {
  let arr1 = [];
  let arr2 = [];
  let row = parseInt(ind / w);
  let col = ind - row * w;
  diagIteration(arr, row, col, l, w, -1, arr1);
  diagIteration(arr, row, col, l, w, 1, arr2);
  return [arr1, arr2];
}

function diagIteration(arr, row, col, l, w, strategy, result) {
  // find the starting row and col to begin with
  while (row - 1 >= 0 && col + strategy >= 0 && col + strategy < w) {
    row--;
    col += strategy;
  }
  // iterate the diagonal elements and add it in result
  strategy *= -1; // since we need to diagonally the reverse way after getting the base indexes to begin with
  for (; row >= 0 && row < l && col >= 0 && col < w; row++, col += strategy) result.push(arr[row * w + col]);
}

// tests
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
  console.log(arr[i] + ' =>', getDias(arr, 4, 5, i));
}
```

- We compute the `row` and `column` for a particular given index. For any given index, the `row` would be `index / width` and `column` would be `index - row * width`.
- Now, we find the base indexes to begin with and iterate over the diagonal as if were a 2D array. The index lying on any diagonal can be computed as  `row * width + column`. We do an additional check to see if we are still in range of the simulated 2D array.

Answer (score -1):

/* you need to start your loop with respect of R and C; if you find the element then you need to break the loop and follow same process.*/

```
function Diagonals(R, C, matrix, K)
{
for(let i=0; i<R;i++)
{
for(let j=0; j<C; j++)
{
if(matrix[i][j]==K)
{
r=i;
c=j;
break;

}
}
}
let sum = r+c;
let diff= r-c;
let left= "";
let right="";
for(let i=0; i<R; i++){
for(let j=0; j<C; j++){
if(i-j==diff){
left=left+matrix[i][j]+" ";
}
if(i+j==sum)
{
right=right+matrix[i][j]+" ";
}
}
}
console.log(left);
console.log(right);

}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and read up on [answering questions well](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering).

Comment: Please format the code to have proper indenting